# ROS+Arduino Servo Error

Tags: ros, arduino, rosseral-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use the standard servo control example found here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Servo%20Controller .  The program works fine, but only once.  When I try to give it a new servo position it never updates.  I have to close all of my terminal windows and reset my Arduino before I can try again.  I am wondering if there is a way to actually reset the PWM to neutral in between commands.  I have tested my servo and it works fine with a normal RC transmitter and receiver.

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 with ROS Electric and an Arduino MEGA 2560.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32137/ros+arduino-servo-error/) by [shakingatoms](https://answers.ros.org/users/1393/shakingatoms/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-04-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yep, I'm having the same problem.  It looks like what's happening is that when we update the servo command with a new command, it simply ORs the bits together.

In other words, if your first command was 5, which is 00000101 in binary, and you send over 3 as your next command, which is 00000011 in binary, the next value will be 7, which is 00000111 in binary.

It looks like this problem has already been solved here

https://kforge.ros.org/rosserial/hg/rev/10cb30606b34

but I don't know how to apply it.

I've removed the old copy of rosserial in /opt/ros/electric/stacks and added the new version from the trunk into my ROS package path, but I still get the same error.

Any thoughts?

(I'm also running Electric.)

UPDATE:  Whoop--it looks like I've discovered the answer! Here's what I did:

Note: I've only gotten this to work with *electric*.

1. Remove the old version of *rosserial*.
2. acquire the updated version of *rosserial* using mercurial here:
   https://kforge.ros.org/rosserial/hg/
3. **rosmake** it and put the *libraries* folder in your Arduino *sketchbook*.
4. Make sure you're using Arduino 1.0

(My problem was that I was still running version 022.)

Hope this helps!

(Thanks, Mike Ferguson!)

---

Originally posted by [Poofjunior](https://answers.ros.org/users/795/poofjunior/) with karma: 88 on 2012-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1